# How to change the column "FLAG" as "To be removed" or "Do not remove" in excel based on Subject ID and measurements in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the Columns that have a corresponding Subject ID, measurements, RPT, Status, and FLAG. I want to update the "FLAG" column "To be removed" or "Do not Remove"  for the rows that have the Maximum RPT value of that particular measurement and subject ID.

Constraints:
The flag "to be removed" should be set for the value that has max RPT and the status should be "Current" of that particular subject ID.

How can I do it in Excel?

**Current output**

```
Measurement SUBJECTID    RPT  Status   FLAG
WBC           123        1    Current
WBC           123        2    Audit
WBC           123        2    Current

RBC           123        2    Current
RBC           123        1    Current
RBC           123        2    Audit
```

**Expected Output**

```
Measurement SUBJECTID    RPT  Status     FLAG
WBC           123        1    Current    To be removed
WBC           123        2    Audit      To be removed
WBC           123        2    Current    Do not remove

RBC           456        2    Current    Do not remove
RBC           456        1    Current    To be removed
RBC           456        2    Audit      To be removed
```

Comment: Is 1 the max here? Is it possible for there to be 2 measurements with a tie for the RPT? i.e. two RBC with RPT 1 and status as current?

Comment: Yes, but the status will be always different, the status value will not be in a tie

Comment: It's unclear why the 2nd and last row should also be set as `To be removed` in your sample data. It doesn't fit two criteria you listed. First, the value is not `Current`, second, it's not associated with the max value. Can you confirm that `1` is the max value? Or am I missing something

Comment: Also, your subject ID is different in your current and expected output. Can you please update and verify the sample data shown is accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you always want to remove the Audit rows, so this formula will also perform that action:

```
=IF(AND(D2="Current",MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2,D:D,"Current")=C2),"Do Not Remove","To be removed")
```

In this formula, it's labeling as "Do Not Remove" if the status is Current and  the RPT matches the max value for each Measurement/SubID group measured by Current status.

[image]